# Detect file played by sound card

Tags: c#, audio

Is there a way to detect what file the sound card is playing from another program(Full Flush Poker.exe) in c#? thanks in advance, google brings up copying audio whenever I search this. Also have the names of the sound files.
or if the wav file changes in size when played maybe i could detect that. Thanks Jeff

Comment: Worth checking out: https://naudio.codeplex.com/

Comment: Any other program? Unless you know that program, it might not even be playing from a file..

Comment: Can get it to specific program Full Flush.exe

Comment: What if the sound is generated as a a stream? For instance with a pipe.

Comment: The sound files are in the programs directory not sure if generated by stream.